# Visual Studio Tool Window Extension installs but window can't be seen

Tags: c#, visual-studio, plugins, vsix

I've created a Visual Studio(Tool Window) Extension, which shows up fine (View/Other windows/ToolWindowName) when running experimental instance.

The problem is once I install it by clicking on VSIX file (so I can see it outside of the experimental instance) I can't  find the window.

How do I debug this?  Is there a VS extension boot log?  Is there a way to see list of all "running tool windows" in VS or maybe reset all positions?

One last note, If I go to Visual Studio's installed extensions, it's there! Uninstalling and reinstalling doesn't seem to fix the issue.

Please advise...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several avenues here, in order of relative ease/merit ratio:

- Reset the Experimental Instance (Start Menu > All Programs > Visual Studio 2015 > Microsoft Visual Studio SDK > Tools > Reset the Visual Studio 2015 Experimental Instance)
- Look at your Visual Studio Activity Log (this VS2015 [extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ab39a092-1343-46e2-b0f1-6a3f91155aa6) will make this considerably easier to do)
- Delete your temporary Asp.Net files (you never know)
- Clone and rename your extension, and I mean fully rename it i.e.

  - new names within VSPackage.cs (options annotations spring to mind)
  - new values within VSIX manifest file (name, product id guid, version)
  - new assembly name within project properties
  - worst case (but one I personally experienced) new solution name and/or new project(s) name and/or new file name(s) and/or options collection path and/or options property name
- Join the [Gitter VS Extensibilty](https://gitter.im/Microsoft/extendvs) room and ask a question (ideally on the third Thursday of the month from 17:00-19:00 UTC, 10:00-12:00 PST, 18:00-20:00 CET)
- Clutching at straws...try installing your VSIX from a different source i.e. instead of double-clicking the VSIX file, publish your VSIX (e.g. to the [VSIX gallery](http://vsixgallery.com/)) & install it from there, and see if that makes any difference

Answer (score 0):

I don't recall what I did to fix this problem, but it was a user error in losing track of where a VS window has been opened.